# Pyspark : Convert Julian Date to Calendar date

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a pySpark DataFrame Column with Julian Dates. I tried to convert the date to Calender Date.

| number | julian_date |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 17196 |
| 2 | 17199 |
| 3 | 17281 |

I tried with the below code:

```
spdf = spdf.withColumn('date_new',functions.to_date(functions.from_unixtime("julian_date")))
```

However, I am getting output as:

| number | julian_date | date_new |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 17196 | 1970-01-01 |
| 2 | 17199 | 1970-01-01 |
| 3 | 17281 | 1970-01-01 |

Please help. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Julian date is consists of 2 year numbers and 3 digits of day-of-year.

For example: 17196 is year 2017's 196th day, which is 2017-07-15.

Thus, you can use `to_date` with using year (y) and day-of-year (D) format. (ref: [date pattern](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-ref-datetime-pattern.html))

```py
df.withColumn('date_new', functions.to_date(df.julian_date, 'yyDDD'))

# If julian_date is not String type.
# df.julian_date.cast(StringType())
```

Comment: I have been trying to solve this... I love you, Emma... you are the best...